# Uneven brake pad wear

Tags: brakes

I have a 2009 Honda Accord.  One of calipers on the rear (floating caliper, single piston) keeps wearing out the outside pad at a rate of about 4000 miles per pad.  Having researched these symptoms, the consensus is that it is seized slider pins that are the problem.  Inside pad wear would usually be a seized piston in the caliper.

The strange thing is that the pins have recently been replaced, and lubricated with silicone lube.  They move as freely as they can, but yet I still have excessive outside pad wear.

Can anyone share any info or advice they have about what could be the problem here?

Comment: Were only the pins replaced, or was the caliper overhauled? If the channels are clogged with grit the caliper won't be able to freely move, simply replacing the pins might not be enough.

Comment: I had cleaned out the channels and checked that the caliper could move freely

Comment: Has there been any accident damage or anything related to that wheel before?

Comment: Not that Im aware of

Comment: It's usually sticky pins as you say in your post, however as you've fixed that then it could be other issues with the caliper and I'd suggest you replace it.

Comment: Isn't 4000 miles for a pad not ridiculously fast to wear out anyway? My front pads are only halfway through and i already drove 18000 miles with them. And those pads were produced in the 70s...

Comment: @Bart it is, that is the problem I have

Comment: I thought you meant that only your outside pads are wearing fast, while the inner ones aren't worn out yet.

Comment: @Bart Yeh, the outside is wearing stupidly fast where as the inside is wearing at a normal rate

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that  in cleaning out the holes for the pins they are oversized or oval. They may slide freely manually but the caliper may twist and bind under braking pressure. Calipers are relatively inexpensive. As @GdD  has suggested I would replace the caliper.